# Link .o file @ xcode to create a KEXT

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel-extension

I have an object file (Created with NASM) and I want to link it with my project @ Xcode in order to get a KEXT file.
Is it possible ? If yes, How do I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a static library (`.a` file) from the object file and this should then be easy to add to the Xcode target.

From the command line:

```
$ ar rc libstuff.a file.o
```

Comment: Okay, and should I just add the .a file into my xcode project? or do anything else ?

Comment: No, you should be able to add it to the project as if it was any other static library.

Comment: I'm getting : archive has no table of contents file 'x.a' for architecture x86_64. what do you suggest?